# How to disable high-lighting in browser PDF viewer (Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

When I view the PDF in Firefox browser , the user are allow to highlight the text on the document and copy it . Are there any way to prevent the user from highlighting the doc?

I am using PDF.js build in FireFox

I tried css approach but it does not work

Attempt 1:

```
::-moz-selection{
background-color:Transparent;
color:#000;
}

::selection {
background-color:Transparent;
color:#000;
}

#zoomPage::-moz-selection,
#zoomPage::selection { ... }
```

Attempt2:

```
$("#zoomPage").disableSelection();
```

Attemp3:

```
    #zoomPage {
        overflow: auto;
        width: 30%;
        height: 20%;
         -moz-user-select: none;
         -webkit-user-select: none;
         -ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

Way to embed pdf

```
<object id = 'zoomPage' type='application/pdf' data= '1.pdf#scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0'><p>The PDF can not display</p></object>
```

The example site:
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: The PDF format offers a possibility to disallow copying text, as you can see when you look at the document properties of a PDF in Acrobat reader. However, I have no idea if and how that property can be set via PDF.js.

Comment: Thanks for your help , and I have to do  (not highlight when grab) besides blocking copying